# Get Domain from URL in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to strip out the domain in this scenario using PowerShell. What is the most effective method to get `example.com` out of the following variable?

```
$URL = "http://www.example.com/folder/"
```

(some sort of regex command here to convert/strip $URL into $DOMAIN using PowerShell)

```
$DOMAIN = "example.com" #<-- taken from $URL
```

I've searched and I've found results for finding the IP address from a domain but I need to establish what the domain is first using regex (or another method).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try the URI class:

```
PS> [System.Uri]"http://www.example.com/folder/"

AbsolutePath   : /folder/
AbsoluteUri    : http://www.example.com/folder/
LocalPath      : /folder/
Authority      : www.example.com
HostNameType   : Dns
IsDefaultPort  : True
IsFile         : False
IsLoopback     : False
PathAndQuery   : /folder/
Segments       : {/, folder/}
IsUnc          : False
Host           : www.example.com
Port           : 80
Query          :
Fragment       :
Scheme         : http
OriginalString : http://www.example.com/folder/
DnsSafeHost    : www.example.com
IsAbsoluteUri  : True
UserEscaped    : False
UserInfo       :
```

And remove the www prefix:

```
PS> ([System.Uri]"http://www.example.com/folder/").Host -replace '^www\.'
example.com
```

Comment: This works nicely, but I might suggest using something like `.Host.split('.')[-2..-1] -join '.'` so it works on a wider range of URLs. (There's probably a less ugly way to do that, just was the first thing that came to mind)

Comment: @ajk Try your code with `"http://domain.com.uk/folder/"` and after with Shay code

Comment: Good point. I don't have a quick way to support both `jubbly.monkey.com` and `domain.com.uk` without giving this more thought than I have to spare. Glad I didn't post a separate answer!

Comment: @Shay, cheers, it worked. I modified it slightly to suit my needs but the URI class was what I needed.

Comment: (Resolve-DnsName -Type SOA www.example.com).Name returns example.com.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
PS C:\ps> [uri]$URL = "http://www.example.com/folder/"
PS C:\ps> $domain = $url.Authority -replace '^www\.'
PS C:\ps> $domain
example.com
```

Comment: @ShayLevy I didn't see your answer in time ;)

Comment: np :), I suggest you target the Host property. Authority will contain the port number is exists.

Answer (score 1):

For properly calculating the sub-domain, the trick is you need to know the second to last period. Then you take a substring of that second to last period (or none if it is only one .) to the final position by subtracting the location of second period (or 0) from total length of domain. This will return the proper domain-only and will work regardless of how many sub-domains are nested under the TLD:

`$domain.substring((($domain.substring(0,$domain.lastindexof("."))).lastindexof(".")+1),$domain.length-(($domain.substring(0,$domain.lastindexof("."))).lastindexof(".")+1))`

Also note that System URI itself is valid 99% of the time but I'm parsing my IIS logs and finding that with VERY long (often invalid/malicious requests) URIs it does not properly parse and fails those.

I have this in function form as:

```
Function Get-DomainFromURL {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Takes string URL and returns domain only
    .DESCRIPTION
    Takes string URL and returns domain only
    .PARAMETER URL
    URL to parse for domain
    .NOTES
    Author: Dane Kantner 9/16/2016

    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
        [Alias("URI")][parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][string] $URL
    )

    try { $URL=([System.URI]$URL).host }
    catch { write-error "Error parsing URL"}
    return $URL.substring((($URL.substring(0,$URL.lastindexof("."))).lastindexof(".")+1),$URL.length-(($URL.substring(0,$URL.lastindexof("."))).lastindexof(".")+1))
}
```

Comment: only works for 2nd level domains. breaks on 3rd level, eg example.co.uk returns co.uk.

Answer (score -1):

Just go with regex like this:

```
[regex]::Match($URL, '(?<=\.).*?(?=[/|$])').value
```

This will get you everything after the first dot till first slash or end of string.