# Extract Domains from List of URLs using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a list of thousands of URLs contained in a CSV file. They're full length, including folders, variables, etc. I'd like to produce a list of the domains for further analysis. I found [this relevant SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363214/get-domain-from-url-in-powershell), but I'm new to Powershell and I'm not seeing how to iterate this over the lines of a CSV.

My CSV has only one column:

```
http://something.net/prod/case_studies.asp
http://www.another.com/prod/group/gold/price_guarantee.asp
http://www.goodsite.co.uk/prod/case.asp?utm_source=google&utm_medium=search
http://wheel.net/prod/studious.asp
http://www.buystrop.com/gap/index.php?page_id=2345&group_id=9876
```

Here's what I'd like to end up with:

```
something.net
www.another.com
www.goodsite.co.uk
wheel.net
www.buystrop.com
```

I've tried several iterations of the code I found in the other thread, but nothing has worked yet. Either I get errors, or the output is blank.

**Edit:**
Here's the code that I've tried so far:

```
$file = Get-Content 'file.csv'
$domains = ForEach ($p in $file) {select ([System.Uri]$p).Host}
```

That gives no error, the code runs but $domains is empty.

```
$domains = ForEach-Object {$file | select-object [System.Uri]$file.Host}
$domains = ForEach-Object [System.Uri]$file.Host
```

These both give an error indicating that it's looking at the entire file, not looping through each line. I've now tried a few dozen variations on these, I haven't yet figured out how parse the URL in each line.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked has the pieces you need. Post the code you're attempting and where you're having trouble, and we can help you with it.

Comment: In your edit, you've misspelled the last `$domains` as `$domians`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Hyper Anthony. I got excited when I thought it was something this simple, but alas, that's not it. Still trying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to loop through each item that you read from the file (which you're not doing in the last 2 examples; you're kind of doing it backwards).

```
$hosts = Get-Content file.csv;
$hosts|ForEach-Object {$url = New-Object System.Uri $_;$url.Host};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer that builds on what alroc showed, but adds making the list of hosts unique:

```
$domains = (gc file.csv)|%{(New-Object System.Uri $_).Host)|select -unique
```

Breaking this down:

- `$domains` is the variable that is going to contain the list of unique hosts
- `gc` is an alias for Get-Content - it reads in the file line by line
- the <kbd>|</kbd> (pipe) character reads each line from `gc` and passes it to the next expression
- <kbd>%</kbd> is an alias for ForEach-Object, and `$_` is a special variable that holds the current value that each is being passed along the pipeline (one line of text from file.csv in this case)
- `New-Object` creates a new instance of the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class with the URL from file.csv
- The parenthesis <kbd>()</kbd> wrap the new object, allowing the property dereference operator <kbd>.</kbd> to be used to access the [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) property of the Uri object. According to the MSDN docs this property contains just the "domain" part of the URL as you call it.
- The resulting hosts are then piped to the `select` cmdlet (alias for Select-Object) that has a switch `-unique` that as you may guess, filters the values coming through it to be just the unique/distinct values.

I hope this helps!