# Powershell - Pulling a substring from a uri

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pull just this

```
hrbkr.com
smqzc.com
znynf.com
```

from a list of uri's in $temp like this -

```
anything.anything.hrbkr.com
anything.anything.smqzc.com
anything.anything.znynf.com
```

This regex seems to match at least on regex101 -

```
(<domainname>(?<ip>^[A-Fa-f\d.:]+$)|(?<nodots>^[^.]+$)|(?<fqdomain>(?:(?:[^.]+.)?(?<tld>(?:[^.\s]{2})(?:(?:.[^\.\s][^\.\s])|(?:[^.\s]+)))))$)*?'
```

But this doesn't seem to give me any results, I am able to get it to match the whole line, but I just want the 'substring' not a true if the line matches.

```
$temp = ‘c:\Users\money\Downloads\phishinglist.txt’
$regex = '(<domainname>(?<ip>^[A-Fa-f\d.:]+$)|(?<nodots>^[^.]+$)|(?   <fqdomain>(?:(?:[^.]+.)?(?<tld>(?:[^.\s]{2})(?:(?:.[^\.\s][^\.\s])|(?:[^.\s]+)))))$)*?'
$temp | select-string -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } | Sort-Object -Unique > $list
$list
```

Thanks!

Comment: The System.Uri class should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363214/get-domain-from-url-in-powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file only contains FQDNs and nothing else, you can solve it easily with a simple `-split` and `-join` operation:

```
# Split FQDN into individual labels
$labels = 'anything.anything.smqzc.com' -split '\.'

# Grab second-to-last and last label, join with a dot
$domain = $labels[-2,-1] -join '.'
```

Or in a single statement:

```
$domain = ("anything.anything.smqzc.com" -split '\.')[-2,-1] -join '.'
```

So your procedure ends up looking like:

```
$list = Get-Content $HOME\Downloads\phishinglist.txt |ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -split '\.')[-2,-1] -join '.'
}
```

Comment: That will work for a domain with a single prefix like .com/net/org but doesn't return correctly for a prefix with two parts e.g. bbc.co.uk or ausregistry.com.au

Comment: Looks like this is a better start than the one I had,  I'll add an if statement with tld array to it, so if it is like @James C. suggested it will grab the last three.  Otherwise, just grab the last two.  I think that will work...  Many many thanks!!!  When I come up with it I'll try and remember to post it back here.